# Получить элементы по описанию свойства строка

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть множественное свойство типа строка: `"CML2_TRAITS"`, нужно получить элементы, у которого поле описание `(DESCRIPTION)` содержит строку `"Зачеркнутая цена"`. 
Вот так возвращает элементы, у которых значение содержит `"2 900"`, а нужно по полю `DECRIPTION`.

```
$arSelect = Array();
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>8, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y", "PROPERTY_CML2_TRAITS" => "%2 900%");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
 $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
 print_r($arFields);
}
```

Вот так работает как нужно, массив `$oldPriceFilter`содержит ID нужных элементов, но тут проблема с быстродействием, сначала происходит перебор всех элементов каталога, а потом из них уже по свойствам. Есть ли решение проще?

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","PROPERTY_*");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>8, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$oldPriceFilter = array();
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
 $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
 $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
 //echo "<pre>";
// print_r($arFields['ID']);
// echo "</pre>"; 
 $oldPriceArray = $arProps['CML2_TRAITS']['DESCRIPTION'];
 if (in_array("Зачеркнутая цена", $oldPriceArray))  $oldPriceFilter[] = $arFields['ID'];
}

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($oldPriceFilter);
 echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Ну так и передавайте это в фильтр вместо 2900 или делайте выборку всех элементов, а потом отслеживает только те у которых значение свойства равно нужному полю. Здесь помогают решить проблему, а не решают за Вас. И нескромный вопрос, зачем вам определение бесполезной пустой переменной arSelect? Могли бы пустой массив в нужном аргументе функции GetList передать.

Comment: `PROPERTY_CML2_TRAITS.DESCRIPTION`?

Comment: @НиколайСарры 2 900 - это значение, а нужно фильтр  по описанию. По значению всё хорошо фильтрует, но элементов около 1000 и у всех разное значение при одинаковом описании. Если передавать вместо 2900 описание "СТРОКА" то фильтр не срабатывает.

Comment: @u_mulder Так тоже пробывал, не работает.

Comment: По-моему, тут надо менять задачу. Такой пример -- прямо в копилку идей "Как не надо готовить Битрикс".

Что вам мешает добавить новое свойство `Зачеркнутая цена`, где ставить галочку? И уже по нему искать. Будет и быстрее, и эффективнее, пусть и с легким налетом денормализации. А в админке можно сделать так, чтобы галочка проставлялась автоматом.

Comment: @AndrewNikolsky Ничего не мешает добавить свойство. Но вопрос у меня другой. Если есть "поле описание, то можно ли по нему как-то осуществить фильтрацию", например, у меня из 1С передаются реквизиты типа строка и под каждый из них добавлять свойство -извините..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ техподдержки: "По полю `DESCRIPTION` фильтрацию проводить нельзя".